How to find events in a time window from a key/value SQL table?
I have events of health records stored as key/value in a SQL table.
For example, the following table events.
PATIENT_ID TIMESTAMP    DOMAIN     KEY           VALUE
1           2021-01-01  biology     Hemoglobin  10
1           2021-01-05  diagnosis   ICD         J32
1           2021-01-10  diagnosis   ICD         J44
2           2018-01-01  biology     Hemoglobin  10
2           2019-01-01  diagnosis   ICD         J32
2           2020-01-01  diagnosis   ICD         J44

From this table, I would like to select all patients with the following critera in a time window of 1 month :
biology:hemoglobin = '10' AND ( diagnosis:ICD ='J32' OR diagnosis:ICD = 'J44' ) 

From the input dataset above, patient 1 and patient 2 have same event but with different time. I want to keep only patient 1 where all events are in  a close time window ( in day, month or what ever ).
Graphical example :
          ----------------timeline---------------->
patient 1      ^           ^             ^ 
patient 2                             ^^   ^
                                 [--time window --]

Without considering the time window, I think I can convert the query above into the following SQL query :
    SELECT patient_id FROM events WHERE domain='biology' AND key='hemoglobin' AND value = '10' 
    INTERSECT 
    (
    SELECT patient_id FROM events WHERE domain='diagnosis' AND key='ICD' AND value = J32
    UNION 
    SELECT patient_id FROM events WHERE domain='diagnosis' AND key='ICD' AND value = J44
    )

But these conditions must be true only within a time window. I use Duckdb, I've seen that there's a WINDOW function but I don't know if it's useful in this case.
Thanks

Provide a complete [mcve], i.e. add some more sample table data and also specify the expected result.

Maybe consider a GROUP BY Year(TimeStamp), Month(TimeStamp).. see https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/functions/datepart

Instead of saying a window of one month (months vary by 28-31 days)..maybe just say the results must be within 30 days of each other.

Sorry, I fixed that with new input,  expected results and a graphical example

J34 = Other and unspecified disorders of nose and nasal sinuses. J32 = Chronic sinusitis.

10 is an extremely low result for hemoglobin.  For men, a normal level ranges between 14.0 grams per deciliter (gm/dL) and 17.5 gm/dL. For women, a normal level ranges between 12.3 gm/dL and 15.3 gm/dL. A severe low hemoglobin level for men is 13 gm/dL or lower. For women, a severe low hemoglobin level is 12 gm/dL.

I suspect this query is looking for patients who are having trouble breathing AND trouble transporting oxygen throughout the body due to low hemoglobin. Either condition by itself can be managed but the combination requires special care.

It doesn't make sense to search for a hemoglobin result of exactly 10. A filter condition of hemoglobin <= 10 would be more useful.

DuckDB supports PostgreSQL date functions. In this solution I first find patients with Hemoglobin=10 results. I then join them with patients who have ICD = J32 or J44 and timestamps with a 1 month window.
WITH  Hem10 as
(  
SELECT PATIENT_ID,ts
FROM Events
WHERE Domain='biology' AND Key='Hemoglobin' AND VALUE='10'
)
SELECT * 
FROM events e
INNER JOIN  Hem10 h on H.Patient_id=e.Patient_ID 
WHERE Domain='diagnosis' AND KEY= 'ICD' AND ( VALUE ='J32' OR VALUE = 'J44' ) 
AND e.ts BETWEEN h.ts + INTERVAL '-1 month' AND h.ts + INTERVAL '1 month'

postgres fiddle



PATIENT_ID
ts
DOMAIN
KEY
VALUE
PATIENT_ID
ts




1
2021-01-05 00:00:00
diagnosis
ICD
J32
1
2021-01-01 00:00:00


1
2021-01-10 00:00:00
diagnosis
ICD
J44
1
2021-01-01 00:00:00




Answer updated to use new input

There's no example output in your question, so it's hard to be sure what exactly do you mean by conditions must be true only within a time window,
but if you need to filter on timestamp you can just add a condition to where clause.
Also, I'd suggest to use in operator for filtering on multiple values:
select e.patient_id
from events as e
where
    e.domain = 'biology' and
    e.key = 'hemoglobin' and
    e.value = '10' and
    <timeframe condition here>

intersect

select e.patient_id
from events as e
where
    e.domain = 'diagnosis' and
    e.key = 'ICD' and
    e.value in ('J32', 'J44') and
    <timeframe condition here>

